# Saving Many to Many relationship - Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

I have the following classes:

```
    public class item
    {
        public int NodeID
        {
            get ;
            set ;
        }
        public int Weight
        {
            get ;
            set ;
        }
        public int Category
        {
            get ;
            set ;
        }
    }
   public class Recipients
    {
        public int RecipientID
        {
            get ; set;
        }
    }

    public class Nodes
    {
        public List<int> RecipientList
        {
            get ;
            set ;
        }
        public item Item
        {
            get ; set;
        }
        public int Capacity
        {
            get ; set;
        }
        public int NodeID
        {
            get ; set;
        }
        public int Weight
        {
            get ; set;
        }
        public int Category
        {
            get ; set;
        }
    }
```

And I tried to save it in my existing DB that has the following tables:

```
1) Category
2) Items
3) Nodes (Node and Items has 1-1 relationship)
4) Recipients
5) NodeRecipients (This table show the many to many relationship between Nodes and Recipients)
```

I use VS2012 to create an EF model as illustrated by the diagram below (please note that Nodes derives from Items in the EF)

[image]

I have a method that tries to save the nodes and its recipients

```
   public void SaveNodeAndRecipient(List<Nodes> MyNodes)
    {
        using (var db = new MyEntities())
        {
            foreach (var n in MyNodes)
            {
                Node n1 = new Node() { NodeID = n.NodeID, categoryID = n.Category, Capacity = n.Capacity };
                db.Items.Add(n1);
                foreach (var r in n.RecipientList)
                {
                    Recipient rep;
                    if (!db.Recipients.Select(x => x.recipientID).Contains(r))
                    {
                        rep = new Recipient() { recipientID = r };
                        db.Recipients.Add(rep);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rep = db.Recipients.Where(x => x.recipientID == r).FirstOrDefault();
                    }
                    Node_Recipient nr = new Node_Recipient(){RecipientID=r,NodeID=n.NodeID};
                    n1.Node_Recipient.Add(nr);
                }
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
   }
```

MyEntities is the EF model and was declared in the appconfig:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyEntities" connectionString="xxxxx" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Everything was fine and compiled with no problem until I tried to savechanges. I got this error (not very descriptive)

[image]

Anyone knows what is going on? I am under the impression that the many to many relationship is the culprit but can not pin point what is causing it.
Please help!

Comment: Hit `View Detail...` to see the inner exception.

Comment: Drop your DB and try it again. Unless you put Migrations or Drop the DB always, every time you change your models you'll get and DbUpdate error

Comment: @nekno: Checked inner exception and got this: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Node-Recipient_Recipient". The conflict occurred in database "MyEntities", table "dbo.Recipient", column 'recipientID'.
The statement has been terminated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're setting `Node_Recipient.recipientID` values, but from your description I'm pretty sure that these **primary key values get generated by the database**. So it is not guaranteed that the values (`r`) will be present when the objects get saved.

Worse yet - it's not even likely that the new `Recipients` will keep the assigned `r` values, so you may create false associations.

Here's what should work for you. See some comments below.

```
foreach (var n in MyNodes)
{
    Node n1 = new Node  { 
                          NodeID = n.NodeID,
                          categoryID = n.Category,
                          Capacity = n.Capacity
                        };
    foreach (var r in n.RecipientList)
    {
        Recipient rep = db.Recipients.Find(r);
        if (rep == null)
        {
            rep = new Recipient(); // see comment 1.
        }
        Node_Recipient nr = new Node_Recipient { 
                                                 Recipient = rep,
                                                 Node = n1
                                                 // See comment 2
                                               };
        n1.Node_Recipient.Add(nr);
    }
    db.Items.Add(n1); // see comment 3
}
```

1. No `recipientId` is set here.
2. Here you set the references in stead of the `ID` values. EF will assign the correct foreign key values "just in time" while saving changes.
3. This marks all object in the object graph under the new `Node` as `Added`, unless they are already know to the context, which is true for the `Recipients` you found by `db.Recipients.Find(r)`.

As for the many-to-many association, the table `Node_Recipient` looks like a pure junction table, i.e. a table with nothing but two foreign keys. There must have been a reason why EF didn't generate a model with a transparent m:n association, without a `Node_Recipient` entity. Normally it would do that. When you generated the model, did `Node_Recipient` contain other columns that you removed later?

If you want this m:n association you may want to try and regenerate the model. This should produce a `Nodes` class with a `Recipients` collection and a `Recipient` with a `Nodes` collection. Setting the associations would then be a matter of adding new recipients to `Node.Recipients`.

Comment: I was wonder why EF didn't generate a model with a transparent m:n association too. No, Node_Recipient has been always like that, no column removed. One thing I noticed, and that may or may not have impact on this issue, was the association between Item and Node. Their primary keys are exact the same called NodeID and they are supposed to be 1-1. That's why I made Node inherit from Item. But before making Node base type to Item, I noticed their association was 1:0 (not 1:1) How do I force 1:1 association so that an exception could be thrown if the 1:1 association is violated?

Comment: You should be able to manage that with the multiplicity constraints of the association in the edmx. But in the data model `Item`'s primary key should *also* be a foreign key to `Node` to make it really hard. But maybe you should ask another question with details about this specific association (class model and data model).

Comment: As for the m:n association, I wouldn't worry too much about it being a visible class now. These junction tables have a way of evolving into business entities because sooner or later users will record data *about* the association. With a visible class you're better prepared for such changing requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at your code, without the exception detail, I'm wondering if your modifications to `n1` need to be done before adding it to the database:

```
Node n1 = new Node() { NodeID = n.NodeID, categoryID = n.Category, Capacity = n.Capacity };

foreach (var r in n.RecipientList)
{
    if (db.Recipients.Where(x => x.recipientID == r).FirstOrDefault() == null)
    {
        Recipient rep = new Recipient() { recipientID = r };
        db.Recipients.Add(rep);
    }

    Node_Recipient nr = new Node_Recipient(){RecipientID=r,NodeID=n.NodeID};
    n1.Node_Recipient.Add(nr);
}

db.Items.Add(n1); // add here, after modifications to n1
```

Comment: Since Node_Recipient is basically a many-to-many relationship between Node and Recipient, I am surprised I have to literally add Node_Recipient records. I would think EF is smart enough to create that record when I add Node then Recipient under Node. Maybe my EF was not set up properly? I am very new to this cool concept so, I may make mistake.

Comment: It's not neccessary to load the info from the database, the approach by Gert Arnold is correct

Comment: I agree, @Gert's looks correct. I was taking a shot in the dark without the error info. Note, however, that `db.Recipients.Find(r)` will still query the database if the object is not present in the context. If there's a 'cache miss', then calling `Find()` is a cleaner, tho semantically equivalent, way of calling `db.Recipients.Where(x => x.recipientID == r).FirstOrDefault()` (no exception for duplicate keys) or `SingleOrDefault()` (with exception for duplicate keys). Passing the lambda expr to either method is also an option instead of using `Where()`.